# Concatenation of lists in Scala

Tags: scala, list, concatenation, scala-collections

I am new to Scala and learning about the language using *Programming in Scala (second edition)*. I came across this topic of List concatenation, I was playing around with the language and got something here:

```
val scooters = List("Activa")
val newCars = List("Ritz")
val allCars = "Toyota" :: "Innova" :: newCars ::: newCars :: newCars
allCars.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
Toyota
Innova
Ritz
List(Ritz)
Ritz
```

Why is this not coming out as

```
Toyota
Innova
Ritz
Ritz
Ritz
```

Comment: use `val allCars = "Toyota" :: "Innova" :: newCars ::: newCars ::: newCars` instead of `val allCars = "Toyota" :: "Innova" :: newCars ::: newCars :: newCars`. notice that at last you are using :: instead of ::: for adding elements of the list. Using :: will add whole List to your new list. If you just want to add elements of the List then use ::: instead of ::

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
"Toyota" :: "Innova" :: newCars ::: newCars :: newCars
```

desugars into

```
(((newCars.::(newCars)).:::(newCars)).::("Innova")).::("Toyota")
```

Notice what happens in the very first step:

```
newCars.::(newCars)
```

it produces the list with two elements: a `String` "Ritz" and a `List("Ritz")` of type `List[String]`, so you obtain

```
List(List("Ritz"), "Ritz")
```

in the first step.

Note that the type of the whole expression becomes quite nonsensical for this context, (`List[Serializable]`, because `Serializable` is the least upper bound of both `String` and `List[String]`), and the compiler can tell you about it, simply declare the type of the expected outcome explicitly:

```
val newCars = List("Ritz")
val allCars: List[String] = "Toyota" :: "Innova" :: newCars ::: newCars :: newCars
allCars.foreach(println)
```

When you declare `allCars` with an explicit type, the compiler will tell you immediately what went wrong:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[java.io.Serializable]
 required: List[String]
    val allCars: List[String] = "Toyota" :: "Innova" :: newCars ::: newCars :: newCars
```

In this way, you don't have to run it and to look at the output, or to cover it by a ridiculous number of tests: mistakes of this kind can be detected at compile time. The obvious fix is ouf course:

```
val allCars: List[String] = 
  "Toyota" :: "Innova" :: newCars ::: newCars ::: newCars
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, the associativity of a method is determined by its last character. If it ends with a colon (`:`), it's right-associative. This means that in `1 :: Nil`, you're calling the method `::` of `Nil`, not of `1`. This is why `1 :: 2` doesn't compile, while `1 :: 2 :: Nil` does.

- `::` is a List method to add a single element at the beggining of the list. Then, if you have a `List[Int]` of size 1 and try to append another list (as a single element), you end up with a list of size 2 and type `List[Any]`.
- `:::` is a List method to add multiple elements.

With all this in mind, you end up with the following code:

```
val allCars = "Toyota" :: "Innova" :: newCars ::: newCars ::: newCars
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... the thing you need to consider here is operator associativity.

```
val newCars = List("Ritz")
```

When you write something like following,

```
val allCars = "Toyota" :: "Innova" :: newCars ::: newCars :: newCars
```

It is actually,

```
val allCars = ("Toyota" :: ("Innova" :: newCars)) ::: (newCars :: newCars)
```

Which is equivalent to,

```
scala> val ll1 = "Innova" :: newCars
// Or
scala> val ll1 = newCars.::("Innova")
// ll1: List[String] = List(Innova, Ritz)

scala> val ll2 = "Toyota" :: ll1
// Or
scala> val ll2 = ll1.::("Toyota")
// ll2: List[String] = List(Toyota, Innova, Ritz)

scala> val rl1 = newCars :: newCars
// Or
scala> val rl1 = newCars.::(newCars)
// rl1: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(List(Ritz), Ritz)

scala> val allCars = ll1 ::: rl1
// Or
scala> val allCars = rl1.:::(ll1)
// allCars: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(Innova, Ritz, List(Ritz), Ritz)
```

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Why `(x :: (x :: x)) ::: (x :: x)` and not `(x :: (x :: (x ::: (x :: x))))`? Test it on `object Foo {
  def ::(i: Int) = { println(i); this }
  def :::(i: Int) = { println(i); this }
}; 

4 :: 3 :: 2 ::: 1 :: Foo`

Comment: because `newCars` is a List in this case. Which make both these  equivalent. Your example has only 1 instance of Foo.

Comment: Well, yeah... Operator associativity is kind of irrelevant for associative operations in general, that's the whole point. But from `(x :: (x :: x)) ::: (x :: x)` it's completely impossible to infer what associativity the `::` and `:::` operators have. It's just some seemingly random parenthesation that just *happens* to compile. With the same parenthesation `(1 :: (2 :: 3)) :: (4 :: Nil)` wouldn't compile at all.

Comment: Its not random... Its just that your `3` needs to be `List(3)` in this case. As `::` is defined on `List` and not `Int`

Comment: "3" doesn't "need" anything, the associativity of operators in Scala **is independent of the operands**. Every operator ending with `:` is right-associative, whether it's `(1 :: (2 :: (3 :: (4 :: Nil))))` or `(1 :: (2 :: (List(3) ::: (List(4) :: Nil))))` or whatever. Just `scala -print` your own program, you will see that it is *actually not* what you've written there.

Comment: I was talking about `(1 :: (2 :: 3))` part in `(1 :: (2 :: 3)) :: (4 :: Nil)`... this will not compile because `::` is not defined for `3` which is an `Int`